# URL parameters from a redirected URL

Tags: node.js, api, redirect, oauth-2.0, request

I am trying to implement an *OAuth2* service where I am able to receive the *Authorization code* from the server and the server redirects me to the redirect_url with the parameter **code** *(where code = Authorization Token (authorization grant code))*. 
Now I need to use this *Authorization token* to make requests to the server. But I cannot get the *token* from redirected URL to use in my application.

**index.js**

```
app.get('/oauth2', function(req, res){
res.redirect('https://api.codechef.com/oauth/authorize? response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&state=xyz&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login');
```

});

With the above snippet I am able to get the *Authorization token* in a redirected URL as:

```
http://localhost:3000/login?code=3f608c5f1a019e51997e77bcXXXXXX643ea875ad&state=xyz
```

Now, I want to get the **code** in the above URL and use it for making requests along with some other parameters. Basically, I need that **code** as a variable in my *Nodejs* application.

Comment: what is running on port 3000? The API or the frontend?

Comment: `req.query.code` if you're using express ???

Comment: After reading your question what I get is you need to have a route like `router.get('/login',...)` in which you can get the code from the query string as in my above comment.

Comment: @AnandUndavia Its my NodeJS Application running on port 3000. @vibhor1997a Yes, I am using express. I tried `res.query.code` but it showed empty `{}`. I had even tried out `res.params.code` but since the URL is a redirected one, that's not helping. Also, I'm sorry for this delay in answering to your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an API that matches the redirected URL.

The API that matches `http://localhost:3000/login?code=<code>&state=<state>` would look like:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => { /** Logic */ })
```

Once you have that, it is trivial to get the code and state from the `req`:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('code', req.query.code)
    console.log('state', req.query.state)
    /** Logic */
    res.json(req.query); // <-- send them back in case you want them in response
})
```

If you are still getting `req.query` as empty object, Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Happy to help! :D